# hover in react add permanent class to DOM node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://fiddle.jshell.net/q8b3vwv8/

this is jquery example, I wrote it within 15 seconds.

But I'm stuck in react for 30 minutes. I've tried this but the class won't stay.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/8wsr7xa1

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            active: null
        }
    }

  onMouseEnter(item){
    this.setState({active: item})
  }

    render(){
        const items = [1,2,3,4,5];
        return (
            <div>
                {items.map((obj,i) =>  
                    <div 
                    key={i} 
                    style={this.state.active === obj ? 
                    {backgroundColor: 'yellow'} : {}} 
                    onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter.bind(this, obj)}>
                    {obj}
                    </div>
                 )}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Really need help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are trying to set one state to several items while only one is active at time. You need somehow track state changes and I made simple solution to have individual states for each item.

```
this.state = {
  active: null,
  activeItems: [false,false,false,false,false]
}
```

Then on mouseEnter I'm setting the state:

```
onMouseEnter(item){
  this.state.activeItems[item-1]=true;
  this.setState({activeItems: this.state.activeItems});
}
```

and finally set color based on state:

```
style={this.state.activeItems[i] ? 
                {backgroundColor: 'yellow'} : {}} 
                onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter.bind(this, obj)}>
```

Fiddle is here: [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mhkbujpx/)

Comment: what if you don't have control over the number of item? this make sense but too complicated to accomplish small task.

Comment: @GialaJefferson I've added an answer in case you don't have control over the number of items. You can check it out.

Comment: I don't see any different than your previous answer, can you explain a little bit what changes you've made?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the control over number of items then you can try the following approach.

```
onMouseEnter(event){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}

render(){
    const items = [1,2,3,4,5];
    return (
        <div>
            {items.map((obj,i) =>  
                <div 
                    key={i}
                    onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter}>
                {obj}
                </div>
             )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is the link to working fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/qz7ph3ya/)

Comment: this worked as well but it involved css. Good solution too.

Comment: Yeah...You are right. It involves CSS but doesn't add any extra complexity for this basic task. :)

Comment: One option could be that you push items that should be selected to an array in mouse handler. Just check before pushing if those already are there.

Comment: but this has limitation, how do you remove other background of div?

Comment: @GialaJefferson Which method are you talking about? Can you please be more specific?